# tool to capture logon screen in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, screen-capture

Is there an application for windows 7 that can capture the logon screen?
There's an app called logon changer but it doesn't actually reflect the logon screen especially if you have replaced the authui.dll file.
The app must not necessarily work like the snipping tool. Just something like , it will run on startup and it will just automatically save the .jpeg or .png file of the captured logon screen. Do you know something like that?

Comment: Use your Cam :)

Comment: Use a VM,Like Virtualbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always RDP or VNC in from a different machine and take a screenshot of that...

[image]

Crop it to your liking and nobody will know the difference.

Comment: but how does VNC do it underneath, I wonder...

Answer (score 3):

Screenshots of logon screens are usually taken from virtual machines. To my knowledge there are no programs that do what you want them to...

Comment: To my knowledge to this is how all those screen shots from places you say "how did they get a screen shot of that?" come from.  Bios screens, etc.

Comment: @Chris Yes indeed...

Comment: Well, there is always a video capture card (I've done this for BIOS screenshots before) but of course that's a bit of a production.

Comment: @Shinrai Ye but that's not software neither is it a screen shot =P

Comment: True, but it is potentially a "tool to capture logon screen" so it's worth mentioning. ;)  (EDIT: I want to make it clear I'm not seriously suggesting anyone go buy a capture card for something like this, that's ridiculous.  But if you happened to have one lying around...)

Comment: @Shinrai Okay, you do have a point! ;) So here's a vote up for your useful comment... =)

Answer (score 1):

http://tweaks.com/software/tweakslogon/

I haven't used the above software, so I cannot vouch for it.  But it's an application to help you change the appearance of the login screen.  It also seems to be able to preview what the login screen will look like.  Maybe you could screenshot that preview?

Comment: Its good but it only shows the default logon screen.

Answer (score 0):

The "Print Screen" (PrtSc) key might already work, try that. Use Alt+PrtSc to get just the active window ([see this article](http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/print-screen/)).

**[UPDATE]** This doesn't work. I'm not deleting this answer to document the fact.

Comment: print screen and then what?  I doubt the screen shot will be there once you authenticate to paste into an image editor to save it.

Comment: I doubt it too but sometimes, odd things work.

Comment: I tried this.  It doesn't work.